# Pioneer 3-dx Microphone?

Tags: ros, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i detect and interpret voices with a pioneer 3-dx? Which accessories should i use? Is there some kind of microphone to detect sounds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48447/pioneer-3-dx-microphone?/) by [StewieG.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3608/stewieg./) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have a definite answer for you, but I would say anything that works for a computer should work on the Pioneer 3-DX.

So I would tell you to maybe look into the [Microphone suggestions by MobileRobots/Adept](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Microphones_for_Peoplebot_and_Pioneer_Audio_Systems), using the [Kinect Microphone Array](http://answers.ros.org/question/43143/capturing-kinect-audio/) or popular choices for that kind of application on PCs. You can also look into specialized Speech Recognition software, such as [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0